What are the recommended parameters for NTRUEncrypt?
I'm looking into NTRU for the first time and I am confused by the variants and the set of parameters. I'd like to use a secure NTRU-based cryptosystem to have a (plausibly) quantum secure PKE offering 128 bits of security.
Is the list of parameters set for NTRU Prime in https://ntruprime.cr.yp.to/nist/ntruprime-20201007.pdf the state of the art? (I also looked at the parameters of the NTRU round 3 NIST submission package on https://ntru.org, i.e. ntru.pdf in the archive dated 2020-10-16 - are these up to date?). I also found a list of different parameters in https://github.com/tbuktu/libntru?tab=readme-ov-file#parameter-sets
What 'variants' of NTRU are deemed secure according to today's knowledge? And where can I find the recommended parameters for it? Is there a consensus forming around sntrup761?
The security analysis of Kyber seems rather well understood, as explained here: https://pq-crystals.org/kyber/ - is there something equivalent (e.g. a survey) for NTRU systems? (This? https://ntruprime.cr.yp.to/warnings.html)
(EDIT: I just read this https://blog.cr.yp.to/20231125-kyber.html which questions the claims around the security of Kyber...)

Bernstein and Lange are very respected scientists in the field of cryptography. They do hold relatively extreme opinions on security of schemes and Elliptic curves as well as security of QC schemes. This is not a critique on them or their opinions - it is a positive to have well respected scientists voice their fact-based opinion strongly and let others question their position. Still, it it is something to keep in mind.

If you are looking to use NTRUEncrypt as opposed to the variant NTRUPrime, you are probably best advised to use the parameter sets outlined in the submission to the third round of the NIST process (as summarised on page 9 of the specification). Although not a standard (and specifically not being selected for further study by NIST), the parameters are assessed as likely to provide the stated security based on current knowledge. To quote from the NIST status report on the third round of their process pp. 39-40

TThe design and parameter choices of NTRU protect against all the attacks known today.
In their specification, analysis is provided for the primal and dual lattice attacks. The
specification analyzes quantum versions of the above attacks as well but notes that all
existing claims of a quantum speedup for lattice reduction algorithms rely on the Quantum-RAM model of computation, which the submission describes as sufficiently unrealistic to
be irrelevant to the security of NTRU in practice.
The NTRU problem was first posed in 1996 and it remains unbroken despite many
research advances in lattice attacks over the past few decades. This long security analysis
provides confidence in the security of NTRU.

Note also the Overall assessment states that it was not selected largely for performance considerations:

As noted by the submitters, NTRU may not be the fastest or smallest among the lattice
KEM finalists, and for most applications and use cases, the performance would not be
a problem. Nonetheless, as NIST has selected KYBER for standardization, NTRU will
therefore not be considered for standardization in the fourth round.

If you would prefer something with an official endorsement by a standards body, there is an older version of NTRUEncrypt specified in the IEEE P1363-1. A draft of this can be seen on the eprint server various parameter sets and their assessed security in 2008 can be found in table 15 of section A.7.1 on page 69. These do not differ significantly from the NIST submission save in the generation of the light polynomials. I believe that some of the P1363.1 parameter sets were deployed in Trusted Computing Group work, but the standard he largely fallen off people's radar.
If you would like to use NTRUPrime, again the parameter sets for the NIST third round should be considered secure. Again quoting the security asessment in the NIST report pp. 40-41

The current version of NTRU Prime has performance and concrete security estimates (e.g., quantitative estimates of the computational resources required for usage and
cryptanalysis) that are roughly comparable to other lattice-based cryptosystems.
As a
result, the current version of NTRU Prime is notable more for its unusual design features,
and claims that it offers higher security in a qualitative sense.

and the overall conclusion

The case for NTRU Prime relies substantially on the claim that its
unusual choice of ring provides a security benefit over the algebraic structures used by the
other lattice candidates, i.e., the claim that (1) there is likely to be an attack that significantly diminishes the security of NTRU, KYBER, and Saber, and (2) no similar attack is
likely to affect NTRU Prime. At the end of the third round, the evidence for these two
points is not particularly convincing.


Thanks @Daniel S that's helpful!
